# specifying engine in knitr

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to embed a Haskell chunk in an RMarkdown document on Windows, like so:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r, engine='haskell', engine.path='C:\\D-data\\program\\haskell\\7.10.3\\bin\\runhaskell.exe'}
main = do print "abc"
```
````

When I evaluate this chunk in RStudio with the option of showing output inline it works fine.

[image: screenshot]

However, when I knit the document I get the following error:

```
Error in engine(options) : 
  Warning: ignoring unrecognised input `:set prog ":script haskell90485ecc528.txt"'
Warning: ignoring unrecognised input `:script haskell90485ecc528.txt'

<interactive>:1:2: Not in scope: `e'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... process_group.block -> call_block -> block_exec -> in_dir -> engine
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:\D-data\program\haskell\7.10.3\bin\runhaskell.exe"  -e ":script haskell90485ecc528.txt"' had status 1 
Execution halted
```

Comment: `engine='haskell', engine.path='ghc'` works for me, see also here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yihui/knitr-examples/master/026-engine-haskell.Rmd. But I do not use Windows.

Comment: Indeed, the engine is `ghc`, not `runhaskell`. And this works fine on Windows. But the `ghc` engine would output nothing here. If you need to run `runhaskell`, you have to write another knitr engine.